# Nextjs SSR does not render HTML

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I am not sure if i understand nextjs SSR correctly.
I have an index page which uses getServerSideProps so i would assume this page prerenders as HTML but it renders only one div, a json object and the nextjs scripts and the page is rendered by JS in the client.

```
...
<body>
<div id="__next"></div>
<script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">{"props":{"pageProps":{"posts":[...
...
```

In the getServerSideProps blog posts are fetched via API and passed down to the components.

app/src/pages/index.tsx

```
...

const HomePage: NextPage<
  InferGetServerSidePropsType<typeof getServerSideProps>
> = (props: HomePageProps) => {
  return (
    <DefaultTemplate dataTestId="index">
      <IndexPage posts={props.posts} />
    </DefaultTemplate>
  )
}

...

export const getServerSideProps = async (context: GetStaticPropsContext) => {
  const data = await fetchPosts()
  const posts = data.posts || []
  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
  }
}

export default HomePage
```

So i would have expected that there would be HTML f.e. like `<article><p>this that</p></article>` as source code.
But it is not and i get the above script tag with json data instead.

Is it correct that there is no plain HTML other than the above div is returned by next?
What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was an early out in one of the wrapping providers.
This prevented to reach the SSR part.

Comment: which provider is making this ..i'm also facing same issue

Comment: It was a custom provider.

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, all of your nested components must be SSR. Otherwise you will get exactly this - only the single outermost `<div>`, JSON with the props and code to render the rest on the client.

Comment: How can i make components SSR? I think getServerSideProps is only applicable on pages.

Comment: Which version of Next.js is this? 12 or 13? You don't have `use client` in your componentss?

Comment: It is 13.4.4 but with the old directory structure. So i guess all components are client components and this will not render to HTML?

Comment: They should unless something is blocking. What is `<DefaultTemplate>`?

Comment: Upvote for helping me along the way. The problem however was something homemade :)